# Run statment only once if loop stops in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

I've been doing something that needs to run an infinite `while` loop inside another infinite `while` loop (don't judge) and breaks if some sort of event happens. I need to run a statement once when the inside loop breaks, without having it modified in the external loop.

I need something like this:

```
while True:
   while condition:
       do stuff
   <run some code when the inside while finishes>

   continue running external loop without running the line inside <>
```

Basically, the reverse of a `while-else` construct.

Edit: I've changed the code to relate to the real problem. I'm really sorry for the mistake. Was bombarded by other stuff and wasn't thinking right.

Comment: Why not move the `<run some code>` just before `break`?

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the statement to run once when the internal while breaks, why not just put it in the if block?

```
while True:
  while condition:
    if other-condition:
      <code to run when the inside loop breaks>
      break

  <continue external loop>
```

EDIT: In order to run only once after the inner loop is finished (without an `if other_condition: ...; break`) you should use the following:

```
while True:
  has_run = False
  while condition:
    <loop code>
  if not has_run:
    <code to run when inner loop finishes>
    has_run = True

  <rest of outer loop code>
```

Comment: Because I messed up the code when I wrote it. Sorry.

Comment: @KuraiHikari It may be that I'm misinterpreting your edit, but it seems like the solution I proposed will still work. If this is not the case, please clarify.

Comment: the thing is, there's no ``if`` and no ``other-condition``. I misinterpreted the problem myself, and posted it wrongly. Your code would work if I were to put ``condition`` instead of ``other-condition``, basically repeating the code.

Comment: @KuraiHikari How do you break out of the inner loop when the event happens, then?

Comment: ``while condition`` is the event checker. I did mess up the question at first. What I need is a way to run some code once the ``while`` finishes, but only once, without it being run every time the external ``while`` is run and ``condition`` is ``False``.

Comment: @KuraiHikari I've edited my answer to include a solution to your current problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: it is a nice solution, but I want to know if there is a is a construct to do it, since this solution isn't the most elegant way. Still, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Add a boolean that you switch after the code has been executed once! This way you can always make things happen just once in a loop. Also, if you want to run the external loop again, the internal loop will start again, and it will break again, so are you sure you only want to run that line once?

```
broken = False
while True:   
   while condition:
       if other-condition:
            break
   if not broken:
       broken = True
       <run some code when the inside while breaks>

   continue running external loop without running the line inside <>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need continue code after `while` loop than use variable `was_break`

```
while True:

   was_break = False

   while condition:
       if other-condition:
            was_break = True
            break

   if was_break:
       <run some code when the inside while breaks>

   continue running external loop without running the line inside <>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pythonic way for this is to use else with while loop. This is how it should be done.

If the else statement is used with a while loop, the else statement is executed when the condition becomes false.

```
x=1
while x:
    print "in while"
    x=0
    #your code here
else:
    print "in else"
```

Comment: The problem with ``while-else`` is that ``else`` will run every time when the condition within the `while` is `False`, so it's a no-go. I need that code to run only once, when the loop finishes.

Comment: `else` doesn't execute if `break` was executed in `while` - OP needs something opposite.